# Невозможность авторизации и последующего вызова метода в VkNet | VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Приложение должно выводить список друзей в ВК, однако на этапе вызова метода возникает ошибка "*VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException: "Метод 'friends.get' нельзя вызывать без авторизации"*".

Однако если не вызывать метод, то авторизация проходит ***успешно*** и на самом сайте пишется что был совершён вход в аккаунт. В чём проблема?

---

*При генерации токена было разрешение доступа offline, так что он "постоянный"*

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var api = new VkApi();

            api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
            {
                AccessToken = "-----"
            });
            Console.WriteLine(api.Token);
            var res = api.Groups.Get(new GroupsGetParams());

            Console.WriteLine(res.TotalCount);

            Console.ReadLine();
            GetFriends();
        }
    }

    private void GetFriends()
    {
        var users = api.Friends.Get(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.FriendsGetParams
        {
            UserId = -----,
            Count = -----,
            Fields = ProfileFields.FirstName,
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По клику на `Button` вы создаете локальную переменную

```
var api = new VkApi();
```

А в методе GetFriends() обращаетесь к полю класса.

```
var users = api...
```

Достаточно будет убрать var в методе `Button_Click`

```
api = new VkApi();
```

Comment: А еще лучше подумать над механизмами, которые не дадут несколько раз нажать на кнопку, чтобы не авторизовываться повторно